# iphone synchronisation contact via cardDav protocol

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to develop an application IOs for synchronizing contacts 
i want to use **cardDav** protocole I try to install baikal server but I dont found any client for ios or api to use ,
any one have idea how integrate a client caraddav in iphone to communicate with the server to send/receive vcard

thanks in advance